# PHP - generate & store xml as string in a variable

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to store a xml as string in a variable so that I can store it in my database.

```
$xml = "<root>";
foreach(...){
    $xml .= "<user id='$id'/>";
}
$xml .= "</root>";
```

When I echo it, it's not displayed at all as if my web brower reads it as html tag. It doesn't even look like $xml is storing those as texts. Now, I'm trying to do it with DOMDocument... not not quite successful yet.  Any tips? :(

- Edited my stupid += mistakes..

Comment: Use `.=` instead of `+=`. and finish off with another `.=` instead of an =.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP uses a `.` as a [concatenate operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), or a `.=` as a shortcut, not a `+` or `+=`.

```
$xml = "<root>";
foreach(...){
    $xml .= "<user id='$id'/>";
}
$xml .= "</root>";
```

Comment: Ummmm sorry. Working over 18 hrs screwed my brain up... I made those stupid mistakes as I wrote the codes here without proofreading... I cannot seem to echo '<hi>';  Is it because my browser assumes that as a html tag?

Comment: Oh... using &#60; &#62; instead of < > solved the issue.

Comment: @Raccoon Yes, generally anything in a `<` or `>` is a HTML tag. You can replace them in your string with `&lt;` and `&gt;` which will then show it normally. Keep in mind to only do this when displaying it, not actually *in* the XML.

Comment: which is safer to store between &#60; and &lt?

Comment: @Raccoon Storing them in a database, I would keep the actual XML proper and just change these when displaying it in a page.